# Adding a new button to form2 by clicking a button on form1

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm trying to write a simple application that opens two forms and displays a "newButton" on Form2 in two different places depending on the number of clicks of "button1" in Form1.

```
int ButtonClick1 = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    ++ButtonClick1;
    Button newButton1 = new Button();
    newButton1.Name = "NewButton1";
    newButton1.Text = "1";
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    switch (ButtonClick1)
    {
              
        case 1:
            button1.BackColor = Color.Red;    
            frm2.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newButton1);
            frm2.Show();
            break;

        case 2:
            button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            frm2.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(newButton1);
            frm2.flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(newButton1);
            frm2.Show();
            break;

        case 3:
            button1.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            frm2.flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Remove(newButton1);
            frm2.Show();
            ButtonClick1 = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Every time I click on "button1" it's creating a new instance of Form2 because of `frm2.Show()` but only with that line, I can see that it's actually doing something.
I don't know how to change it so that it would just update Form2 without opening new instances.

Comment: Remove this: `Form2 frm2 = new Form2();`. When you first create a new Form2, store its instance, so you know whether you have already created it or if it's been disposed. If it's `null` or `IsDisposed`, create a new instance and show it (`Show()` brings up the current instance) -- Add a public method to Form2 that accepts an `int` (counter) argument. Call this method passing your `ButtonClick1`. Move the rest of the code to Form2 (i.e., don't change the Access Modifier of Controls to `public`, use the Parent Form to access these Controls while it performs an action that is defined `public`).

Comment: A method that accept a new button (to be added) and source button (that was clicked) and the counter variable as reference will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have identified two things that need to happen to achieve your desired outcome:

1. Manage the visibility of Form 2
2. Have Form 2 respond to property changes in Form 1.

To keep the clutter to a minimum, I'll provide a link where you can browse the example code. This answer will focus on how to achieve the outcome in the `FlowLayoutPanel` controls in `Form2` when the button is clicked in `Form1`.

[image: shows the three count states]

---

**Property Change for ClickCount**

One clean approach is to make a bindable `ClickCount` property in `Form1` and a `Button` to increment it. Whenever that property changes, it fires a `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    int _ClickCount = 0;
    public int ClickCount
    {
        get => _ClickCount;
        set
        {
            // Detect changes and notify when that happens
            if(_ClickCount != value)
            {
                _ClickCount = value == 3 ? 0 : value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                    this,
                    new ClickCountPropertyChangedEventArgs(
                        nameof(ClickCount), 
                        ClickCount));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor for `Form2` will bind this event source to a `PropertyChanged` handler:

```
public Form2(INotifyPropertyChanged binding)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    binding.PropertyChanged += Binding_PropertyChanged;
}
```

One really nice thing about doing it this way is that `Form1` doesn't need to know *anything* about `Form2` (like whether it does or doesn't have `FlowLayoutPanel` controls or what `Form2` might plan to do with the information) and also would be *unaffected* by future changes to those things.

---

**Handling the ClickCount changed event**

When the `PropertyChanged` handler in `Form2` detects that the count has changed, it calls a specialized handler:

```
private void onClickCountChanged(int count)
{
    labelClickCount.Text = $"Click Count = {count}";
    buttonShowOrHideA.Visible = count == 1;
    buttonShowOrHideB.Visible = count == 2;
}
```

You're probably wondering what happened to the "add" and "remove" statements for the buttons? Well here's the thing: why not let `FlowLayoutPanel` do its job of rearranging the layout when buttons are shown or hidden? This way, all you have to do is place the buttons in the designer *and* you can subscribe to their click events just *one* time instead of having to do that every time the button is added or removed. It takes less overhead and there are fewer things to go wrong. Here are the handlers for the Red and Green buttons:

```
private void buttonShowOrHideA_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
    MessageBox.Show("Red one clicked");

private void buttonShowOrHideB_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
    MessageBox.Show("Green one clicked");
```

[image]

---

**Showing and hiding Form2**

Being able to show and hide `Form2` repeatedly *and* keep it out in front of `Form1` means making sure the Form2 gets disposed properly (in the end) but not prematurely and I would encourage you to browse the full code for this. The main highlight is that when the `ShowForm` checkbox is true for the first time, it will instantiate `Form2` by passing in a reference to itself.

```
if (checkBoxShowForm2.Checked)
{
    if (_form2 == null)
    {
        _form2 = new Form2(binding: this);  
    }
    _form2.Location = new Point(Location.X + Width + 10, Location.Y);
    // Passing 'this' ensures Form 2 will stay in front of Form 1
    _form2.Show(owner: this); 
}
else _form2.Hide();
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/button_clicks_with_two_forms.git) this sample.

Comment: Can I somehow get it to work with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#Anchor_7) code for remembering the size of each form or does it need to open Form2 in Form1? I tried to change it so that the showing Form2 part is in MyApplicationContext Class, but then my Form2 does nothing after clicking on the button.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem swapping out for that style of `Form` management, but it's _very_ important that the `PropertyChanged` event of `Form1` gets subscribed to by `Form2` in one way or another. Did you download and run my sample?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded, analyzed it, and changed my code based on your sample. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not trying to nitpick but isn't it a much complex solution to a much simpler problem?

Comment: @AbhinavPandey binding using `INotifyPropertyChange` forms the basis for design patterns like [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel). By setting up the form interactions in this manner, the unstated intention was to set up this or any project such that it's easier to implement and maintain in a standard, portable manner (e.g. so that the developer won't have to start from scratch to do the iOS and Android implementations when the time comes). And like a lot of learning curves, it isn't really complex once one begins to recognize these standard patterns.

Comment: It's definitely _simpler_ from the POV that buttons are no longer being added and removed all the time, and another big win is that `Form1` doesn't need to be modified at all if the implementation of `ClickCount` in `Form2` changes in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on what you are trying to achieve:

Form 1:

```
public partial class testform1 : Form
{
    testform2 form2;
    int cnt = 0;
    public testform1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ++cnt;
        if (form2 == null)
        {
            form2 = new testform2();
        }
        form2.Show();
        Button btn = new Button()
        {
            Text = "1",
            Name = "NewButton1",
        };
        form2.AddButton(btn, (Button)sender, ref cnt);
    }
}
```

---

Form 2:

```
public partial class testform2 : Form
{
    public testform2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void AddButton(Button NewButton, Button ParentButton, ref int counter)
    {
        switch (counter)
        {
            case 1:
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(NewButton);
                ParentButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case 2:
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveByKey(NewButton.Name);
                flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(NewButton);
                ParentButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case 3:
                flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.RemoveByKey(NewButton.Name);
                ParentButton.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                counter = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can pass the counter as reference in the AddButton method to update the value once it reaches 3.

Comment: I tried your code and it's doing well, but I don't want to clear my whole FlowLayoutPanel, I just want to remove that one button1 so that I can store other buttons and labels in that FlowLayoutPanel. When I changed it from clear to remove(NewButton) it does not work. Also when I start my program it is already showing those two forms with that code: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#Anchor_7) and I want to work with just those two forms.

Comment: @Michael `remove(NewButton)` will not work because NewButton is a new instance every time the button is clicked and hence it cannot remove the old instance despite of having same name and text. To Resolve this problem you can use [`Controls.RemoveByKey(String Key)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removebykey). Look at the modified code.